# expo app.json plugins makes appcenter ios(only) failed

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Either by trying to use azure to upload the `.ipa` to appcenter manually, or using the pipelines in Azure, I'm receiving the following error...

## Error

```
Loading release id failed: A problem occured while extracting your app. (Correlation ID: my_uuid)
```

If I don't use any plugins in the app.json(config for expo), it works fine. I've tried 3 different plugins as well as the plugins being empty all resulting in the same error.

## expo config for app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MY PROJECT",
    "slug": "MY-Project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/qa-icon-1024.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "backgroundColor": "#001689",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/qa-splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#001689"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.example.myproject",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/qa-icon-1024.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#001689"
      },
      "package": "com.example.myproject",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "my_uuid"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "minSdkVersion": 23,
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "33.0.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

## expo config app.json fails(same error) with different plugin options

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": []
  }
}
```

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": ["expo-camera"]
  }
}
```

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "minSdkVersion": 23,
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "33.0.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Again, if I remove the plugins completely from app.json, appstore successfully will upload the .ipa file, and everything works as expected to.

## package.json(to show which expo version and packages I'm using

```
{
  "name": "MY-Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --port 8082",
    "android": "expo run:android --port 8082",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.6",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.8.3",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "^2.6.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "yup": "^1.2.0",
    "zustand": "^4.4.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-jest-hoist": "^29.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-header": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.4.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed the issue for me:

- Update macOS Sonoma 14.2
- Update xCode 15.1

After doing these updates everything worked fine.